# Simulink Device Driver Block not executing on arduino mega 2560

Tags: matlab, arduino, driver, device, simulink

I'm working on a project which involves creating a device driver block using simulink and an s-function builder block. My driver is supposed to make my arduino mega 2560 to periodically send a message to a remote sensor and recieve back the temperature measurement of this sensor. 
For the communication between my main arduino and the remote sensors I am using the RF22B 433Mhz transceiver with the Radiohead library (http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/index.html).

I tried my script on the arduino IDE and it works perfectly, but it won't execute on simulink. 
I have installed the simulink support package for arduino and I made some simple driver blocks which involved blinking LEDs and simple stuff and it did work. However, for the script which uses the Radiohead libaray, even though I debugged all of the errors and simulink says that the model is "succesfully deployed to arduino mega 2560", it does not execute.

Does anyone have any hints on why this may be happening?
Has anyone experienced similar issues?

I did some research on this website and many others but I wasn't able to find any similar problems.

Thanks in advance